# Adding virtualization to Table with grouped rows in React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-virtualized

I have a working version of a Material UI table with **Grouped rows**.
https://codesandbox.io/s/1qzy3vvqp4

Now I need to be able to handle huge number of rows (with grouping).

Has anyone done this before? How do I approach this?

- Does `react-virtualized` have some functionality which I can use?
- Should I try to figure out my own calculations based on `scrollHeight` and `scrollY`. If yes, how will that look like since my data is split into multiple arrays for grouping?

Comment: Have you found a work around for this ? I'm also in need of the same. anyway i have used your code to make it work with the grouping. But unable to handle the pagination properly. I'm using material-ui table pagination built-in features.

Also i have seen there is a plugin built-upon material-ui some advanced features, unfortunately it is not for free. pls refer following link too.
https://devexpress.github.io/devextreme-reactive/react/grid/demos/featured/tree-data/

Comment: Yes. The above codesandbox link was as far as I got, and it is now running without pagination or windowing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd love to see the working example (as I was searching on options to group in react tables), but the link is down.

Based on the leftover information, however, without looking at the code I'd say:

1. Yes. And by their own recommendation, take a look at [react-window](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window), which is a re-written version of the former.
2. There's also a lib that you can use that can take care of that: [react-virtualized-auto-sizer](https://npmjs.com/package/react-virtualized-auto-sizer)